# How to extract certain parts of string values in column and turn them into columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
val
"ID: abc\nName: John\nLast name: Johnson\nAge: 27"
"ID: igb1\nName: Mike\nLast name: Jackson\nPosition: CEO\nAge: 42"
...
```

I would like to extract Name, Position and Age from those values and turn them into separate columns to get dataframe which looks like this:

```
Name  Position     Age
John     NaN        27
Mike     CEO        42
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

- Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) inside a list comprehension to get capturing groups for each string ("key") in the list `cols`. Each series thus produced will get the appropiate column name this way.
- Next, we pass the result to [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1` to combine the individual series.
- (You could potentially do this in one go with [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), but whether that works, depends on the order of the different capturing groups. E.g. if the order is *always* the same, this can work.)

```
cols = ['Name', 'Position', 'Age']
res = pd.concat([df.val.str.extract(fr'(?P<{col}>(?<={col}: ).*)\n?') 
                 for col in cols], axis=1)

# e.g. for "Name", we'll look for all chars preceded by "Name :" and followed 
# by "\n", and same for "Position". Question mark at the end is necessary for "Age" 
# (or any other such category that comes at the end)

print(res)

   Name Position Age
0  John      NaN  27
1  Mike      CEO  42
```

**Option 2**

- Instead of relying on regex patterns, we could also resort to [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html). First, we split on `\n` and use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to get rows with "key: value" pairs (but as strings, of course).
- Next, we apply `split` again, but on `:` , and now add `expand=True`.
- We will now have one column (`0`) that contains all the keys, and another (`1`) that contains the associated values. We use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to turn the values in the first column into the column names and get the values from the second column as data.
- Now, we just keep only the columns that we are interested in (i.e. `['Name', 'Position', 'Age']`).
- N.B. you could reverse these last two steps, of course. E.g. do `res[res[0].isin(cols)]` and only then apply `pivot`.

```
cols = ['Name', 'Position', 'Age']

res = df.val.str.split('\n').explode().str.split(': ', expand=True)\
    .pivot(columns=0, values=1)[cols]

# cosmetic (because of `pivot` columns.name will be `0`)
res.columns.name = None

print(res)

   Name Position Age
0  John      NaN  27
1  Mike      CEO  42
```

Answer (score 0):

I had saved your Input data frame as text file and did this.
[Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgI1h.png)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Last name', 'Position', 'Age'])
file =open('File_path&name.txt','r')
L = file.readlines()
line_count = 0
for line in L:
    d={}
    s = line[1:len(line)-2]   
    k =s.split('\\n')  
    for i in k:
       t = i.split(': ')
       d[t[0]] = t[1]
    line_count += 1
    df = df.append(d,ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTbrT.png)

output:

## here its not formatted properly check the images

```
 ID  Name Last name Position Age
```

0   abc  John   Johnson      NaN  27
1  igb1  Mike   Jackson      CEO   4

Process finished with exit code 0